# Block Storage, Root Device and Root Device Volume difference

Tags: amazon-web-services

So I got this info about root device here from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347768/what-means-to-be-a-root-device-on-ec2):

> The **root device** is the **virtual device** that houses the
>   partition where your filesystem is stored -- ephemeral devices have it
>   running on the same physical host at the server, and EBS devices have
>   it mounted using iSCSI.

And from [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ComponentsAMIs.html#storage-for-the-root-device):

> All AMIs are categorized as either backed by Amazon EBS or backed by
>   instance store. The former means that the **root device** for an instance
>   launched from the AMI is an **Amazon EBS volume** created from an Amazon
>   EBS snapshot. The latter means that the **root device** for an instance
>   launched from the AMI is an **instance store volume** created from a
>   template stored in Amazon S3.

So the root device can be either **Amazon EBS volume** or **instance store volume**, right? Then what is the root device volume? Is it the same thing?

And from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/?nc1=h_ls) I got:

> (Amazon EBS) provides persistent **block storage volumes** for use with
>   Amazon EC2 instances in the AWS Cloud.

That means that by using **Amazon EBS volume** you utilize **[block storage](https://www.quora.com/What-is-block-storage)** technology, is that correct?

Comment: The root device is the disk device that the OS selects to boot from. It can be either EBS or instance store depending on your EC2 instance type. This link might help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html